# Javascript-like || in php

Tags: javascript, php

In `javascript`, I can use, for example such statement:

```
window.foo = window.foo || [];
```

If there's no `window.foo` it will be assigned to array, but won't be converted into `boolean`.

But if I will do such thing in `php`, I will get either `true` or `false`. (ig. `boolean` result, not variable equal to `true` value)

Why such difference exists?

**PS** the question is not about what to use instead, the question is about why it is.

Comment: @k102 I know and use it, especially short form `?:` for this, just wondered about the difference between languages

Comment: "Why the difference?" - Because the two languages implement the logical or operator in two different ways. It's different. Because it's different.

Comment: It's different because it's different. If there were no differences, every language would be the same.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to ask why PHP does something the way it did. The answer is usually quite scary.

Comment: @Wobble Why PHP implemented the logical or operator to return a Boolean, like, oh, I don't know, most other languages?!

Comment: @deceze: because it seemed like a good idea at the time?

Comment: @Wobble Because it's one perfectly valid way of doing it?!

Comment: in php you can use `??` ( double question mark ) to achieve this: `$name = $isset ?? "john";`

Comment: @Nabi this was asked 8 years 2 months ago and closed, you are 8 years 2 months and 2 major versions of PHP late to the party.

Comment: @baldrs I did this because I searched on google and only found this topic. :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is in what the operators return. In PHP, the logical operators return boolean values. In JavaScript, the logical operators return the actual operands and rely on implicit conversions to turn them into booleans when the context requires it.

If you want the functionality of returning the first operand if it evaluates to TRUE and the last otherwise in PHP, you can use the short-hand form of the ternary operator (`?:`):

[PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) says:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Comment: I am always interested in improving myself and my current and future answers, so leaving a comment to accompany the -1 would be most welcome.

Comment: I did not downvote, but could for such statement "returning the first operand if it is ok". I do not know PHP, but I doubt there's an "OK" concept ;)

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the comment. I thought the quote from PHP.net would give the answer enough accuracy and allowed for a more informal definition. Upon re-reading i realized informality didn't add anything, so i fixed it according to your suggestion.

Comment: in php you can use `??` ( double question mark ) to achieve this: `$name = $isset ?? "john";`